# How can I edit Color of a cell or range of cells in Google Spreadsheet through Google Spreadsheet API

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I am using *Java* **Google Spreadsheet API** and want to **change** the **color** of a **cell** or **range of cells**.
I have gone through api documentation

1. https://developers.google.com/google-apps/spreadsheets/#changing_contents_of_a_cell
   and the Classes
2. https://developers.google.com/gdata/javadoc/com/google/gdata/data/spreadsheet/CellEntry
3. https://developers.google.com/gdata/javadoc/com/google/gdata/data/spreadsheet/Cell

but couldn't find a way

Any Help would be great.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is there any solution of the problem?

Answer (score 1):

I might be wrong, but I don't think this is possible through the Java API.

It's possible through the [Google Apps Script API](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_range#setBackgroundColor) though.